# Cannot launch ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

Cannot launch ImageMagick after upgrading to Ubuntu16.04. After launcded, it appears on the tool bar for a short time, and then disspears. Launching on terminal by entering "display" can run it with no problem. What should I do? Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do `apt-cache policy imagemagick` and if it is not installed then do `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

Comment: I guess you mean Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 7):

The terminal command to launch the ImageMagick GUI window is

```
display
```

or

```
display-im6
```

Comment: I have similar problem : display
display: error while loading shared libraries: libIlmImf.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I think that I have to remove openexr and imagemagic and install them from source

Comment: @Adam This is completely unrelated, please ask a new question about your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

"Display in terminal". I use linux mint and find the icon twice as a Linux Mint menu item, but "Show" checkbox was not selected. One command was "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/display %f", other "/usr/bin/display-im6 %f". The later works as a terminal command. Only %f gives error and do not show ImageMagick menu by default. Anyhow taking "%f" away it worked. Menu item configuration could be reached right click at "Menu".